# How to remove ascii characters from a string in r

Tags: r, ascii

Perhaps I dont understand the nuances of ascii but I am failing to remove encodings from a string.

**The input string is:**

```
mystring<-"complications:  noneco-morbidity:nil \\x0c\\\\xd6\\p__"
```

**My desired output is:**

```
"complications:  noneco-morbidity:nil __"
```

**My attempt is:**

```
iconv(x, "latin1", "ASCII", sub = "")
```

but nothing is removed

Answer (score 1):

Use the following pattern as a regular expression with `gsub`:

```
"[\\x00-\\x7F]+"
```

This expression matches any non-ASCII character and gsub removes it (`replacement=""`)

Example:

```
gsub(pattern = "[\\x00-\\x7F]+", replacement = "", "complications:  noneco-morbidity:nil \\x0c\\\\xd6\\p__")

[1] "complications  noneco-morbiditynil cdp__"
```

Comment: Warning: This removes the `:` character, I'll try to see if there is an alternative expression that doesn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

Below is not a clean solution. But still might be useful.

```
gsub("x0c|xd6|\\p|\\\\","", mystring)
```